# preg_replace Function in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using `preg_replace` function to remove a list of stop words. Currently, I have an array containing a lst of stop words. As the parameter for `preg_replace` I use this as the first argument (i.e, `preg_replace(^$stopwordlist$, '',$string)` As you can see I'm also using `^$` as I need to match word exactly.However I'm getting the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected '^', expecting ')' in
```

Thanks

Comment: Need string, regex delimiters.

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: Have you ever learned the basics of PHP ? Please start from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @user1926567 what if you use this code `preg_replace('/^'.$stopwordlist.'$/', '',$string)`

Comment: ^ and $ don't work like you think they do. What you're really saying by including ^ at the beginning and $ at the end is that you want to replace it if the _ENTIRE VALUE OF $string_ matches what you're passing to it. Put a space before and after each element in the `$stopwordlist` array, and do away with the ^ and $

Answer (score 1):

If `$stopwordlist` is an array you might want to [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it first.

As for the syntax error, you need to put the `^` and `$` in quotes, you're also missing delimiters in your regex.

Change your code to something like this:

```
// Implode with a |, which is basically an 'or' statement is regex
$pattern = '/^' . implode('|', $stopwordlist) . '$/';

// Replace them
$replaced = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

If you need a place to test your regular expression, try [gskinner.com's RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match exact words, REG EXPs and `preg_replace` are not what you need.

Give a look at `str_replace` or `strtr` documentation to find out which one you need.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$string=str_replace($stopwordlist, "", $string);
```